# XSLT attribute change based on Value

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and wanted to see if I could have some help.

I currently have an XML that consists on numerous  copy of the format below:

```
          <item:items>
            <item:item action="ingest" id="USAUS868509">
                <item:itemID>1157245</item:itemID>
                <item:spotType>commercial</item:spotType>
            </item:item>
           <item:items>
```

What I have been tasked with is to replace the value of the id attribute. I need to change this value based on the numerical portion of the code. if the value is greater than 850000 the format should be changed to USA868509. If the value is less than 850000 than you would change the id value to only include the numbers. The rest of the values in the XML should remain exactly the same.

I currently have the xslt below:

```
             <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                   </xsl:copy>
              </xsl:template>

             <xsl:template match="//items/item[@id]">  
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="substring(id,5) &gt;= 845986">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="substring(id,5)"/>
                        </xsl:attribute> 
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">
                            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                        </xsl:attribute> 
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:template>
```

I am having trouble identifying the value I would like to change because XSLT does not do looping for variables. Is there a way I can change my XSLT to have this logic?

Comment: Please note that an element whose name is `item:items` cannot be selected by the expression `items`. You need to read up on namespace declarations and the use of prefixes in XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us have the following **well-formed** input example:

**XML**

```
<items>
  <item action="ingest" id="USAUS849999">
    <itemID>1157245</itemID>
    <spotType>commercial</spotType>
  </item>
  <item action="ingest" id="USAUS850001">
    <itemID>1157246</itemID>
    <spotType>commercial</spotType>
  </item>
</items>
```

Applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@id">
    <xsl:variable name="code" select="substring(., 6)" />
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:if test="$code >= 850000">USA</xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="$code" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item action="ingest" id="849999">
      <itemID>1157245</itemID>
      <spotType>commercial</spotType>
   </item>
   <item action="ingest" id="USA850001">
      <itemID>1157246</itemID>
      <spotType>commercial</spotType>
   </item>
</items>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!